# How to insert 50 million products in database using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, size, heap-memory

I want to insert 50 million products in database using Node JS.
I have used

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js
```

I have increase --max-old-space-size to 6 GB but still it will stopped it around 6 million with error

> JavaScript heap out of memory

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully imported 60 million products.

Need to work on these things to work it around.

- Mysql connectionLimit
- connectTimeout
- insert products in batches
- log for insertion to check when the query is stooped and check the reason behind it.
- Run it as background on server to check speed per min. to estimate the time
- Run to 2.5 days to insert all products